# Not able to create Heroku account that was made in the Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working on my first rails application and I have just pushed it to production through Heroku. The next step in my assignment is to create an account in production and have it send an email confirmation to that email.

```
config/environments/production.rb

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'alex-bloccit.herokuapp.com' }


config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

if Rails.env.development?
   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
     port:           '587',
     authentication: :plain,
     user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
     password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
     domain:         'heroku.com',
     enable_starttls_auto: true
   }
end

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?

config/initializers/devise.rb

config.mailer_sender = "alex.colbert1987@gmail.com"
```

The code updates to github and pushes to Heroku just fine, but when I go to the website and I attempt to create an email under the email. Hope this provides enough information to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`, you have `if Rails.env.development?` before the ActionMailer configuration. This config won't be run in production because of the way the if statement is structured.

Comment: Notice that it says `if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env production?`. So that shouldn't affect it.

Comment: From what you pasted, the `Rails.env.development?` is in the configure block, not the additional line. Was this a paste mistake?

Comment: Also, I would not include your personal email or host or frankly any other identifiable information in code.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I missed that other place. That would seem to be the issue.

Comment: Cool - glad you figured it out. Would you mind accepting the answer?